# Run VBA format code on all sheets with different number of rows

Tags: vba, loops, excel

VBA noob here needs a little bit of assistance.  I cannot seem to find a solution or get something to work.

I've tried to simplify it as much as I could to get a proof of concept.

The basic idea is to format one cell (A1 say) with all borders, copy that format down across all data in the first sheet (A1:C10 for example), then do the same with data in subsequent sheets.  What I'm struggling with is that subsequent sheets all have a different number of rows and anything I try just formats the additional sheets to the (A1:C10) of the original even if there is no data present.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a variable that identifies the last row of any given sheet. For instance

```
LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(65000,1).end(xlup).row
```

Now you can loop through your cells

```
for i = 1 to LastRow
  for j = 1 to 3
    Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(i, j)  (apply your formatting)
  next j
next i
```

Comment: 65000 is a safe way to go, since excel 2003 only has that many rows, and would break if you went higher - but you could use the Rows.Count method- `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row`  But this trick for getting the last row is the go-to for this exact problem

Comment: Yes, I've made the mistake of using 1M rows, but as you say, that won't do in excel 2003. Also, if you need to identify the last column (say column C isn't always the last one), I use something like `LastColumn = Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(1, 250).end(xltoleft).column` Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, but what if the worksheet names are also dynamic?

Comment: You could just use `ActiveSheet` or if you are in a particular sheet when running it, just don't refer to a specific sheet (e.g., `cells(i,j)`)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the last row in a column by using this VBA code:

```
lastrow = Sheets("SheetName").Cells(rows.count,columnnumber).end(xlup).row
```

Change columnnumber to the number of the column you are looking in, for example column A = 1.